# Can I find my car with my portable device?

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development, ubuntu-touch

Is there any software on Ubuntu which allows me to find my car with my tablet or cell phone which is running Ubuntu Touch? When I lost my car, I would like to use Ubuntu Touch on my portable device to locate it.

Comment: Could you add examples of such apps that currently exist on other platforms for future reference?

Answer (score 2):

No, such a application does not currently exist for Ubuntu Touch as far as I'm aware of - see [this list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Collection) of currently exist apps, but others do also exist.

Developers might create one in the future - especially if there will be a demand for it.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the Bluetooth compatibility there is no other software compatibility device in Ubuntu. Having its demand in future they may get it soon. The upcoming android auto may help you with a number of safety features.

[copart auto auction](http://www.salvageautosauction.com)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a map/navigation application? If you do, then I expect that you would be able to set a marker on the actual map and then use navigation prompts to get you back to your vehicle.

There is a Google Now card that does this (seems to work OK on my Android).